# How to execute shell commands in Automake/Makefile.am?

Tags: makefile, gnu, autotools, autoconf, automake

After I compile my executable using Automake, I want the executable to output the date compiled, compiler used, and git repo version/date. However, I can't seem to get shell commands to run from Makefile.am. When I try, I get these warnings:

> sample/C++/Makefile.am:1: warning: date +%D: non-POSIX variable name
>
> sample/C++/Makefile.am:1: (probably a GNU make extension)
>
> sample/C++/Makefile.am:2: warning: git --no-pager show --date=short --format="%ad" --name-only | { read first _ ; echo $first ; }: non-POSIX variable name
>
> sample/C++/Makefile.am:2: (probably a GNU make extension)
>
> sample/C++/Makefile.am:3: warning: git --no-pager describe --tags --always --dirty: non-POSIX variable name
>
> sample/C++/Makefile.am:3: (probably a GNU make extension)

If there is a better way to do this besides running the commands in configure.ac (because that defeats the purpose of having a compile time) please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX `make` and many specific `make` implementations provide no mechanism for running shell commands outside of recipes.  GNU `make` and perhaps others do provide that as an extension, but one of the objectives of the Autotools is to support the widest variety of build environments possible, so relying on extensions provided by specific  implementations is contrary to Autotools idiom.

One way to approach the problem without relying on extensions would be to make your sources `#include` a header that is generated dynamically at build time.  For example, here's how the `Makefile.am` part might look:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello

hello_SOURCES = \
  hello.cpp \
  build_details.h

BUILT_SOURCES = \
  build_details.h

CLEANFILES = \
  build_details.h

build_details.h:
    echo "#define BUILDDATE \"`date +%D`\"" >$@
    echo "#define COMPILER \"$(CXX)\"" >>$@
```

Because it is listed among the `BUILT_SOURCES`, target `build_details.h` will be built early.  Because the rule for building it has no prerequisites, it is always considered out of date, so it will be rebuilt, thus getting the fresh details.  Of course, this also means that all sources that depend it will be rebuilt every time you run `make`, but maybe that's actually what you want if you're tracking this kind of build info.

On the other hand, if you're willing to depend on GNU `make` extensions, then they provide a way to set variables to the output of shell commands.  In that case you might do something more like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello

builddate := $(shell date +%D)
CXXFLAGS = -DBUILDDATE='"$(builddate)"' -DCOMPILER='"$(CXX)"'

hello_SOURCES = \
  hello.cpp
```

Note the double quotation: the inner double quotes need to be part of the replacement text of the macros being defined, so they need to be protected from the shell as they appear on the compiler command line.

This has the advantages that it is shorter, and that it will not cause `hello` to be rebuilt if `hello.cpp` has not changed. But it will only work with a `make` that supports the GNU extensions used.  Also, this does not cause any objects to be out of date, so it may leave open the possibility of stale build info being recorded in the binary as a result of the object that holds it not being among those rebuilt on some given `make` execution.

Of course, although I've addressed the question as posed, it is worthwhile to note that some of this is duplicative of features that exist directly in the C and C++ languages.  Specifically, the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros are automatically defined to expand to the date and time of compilation.  They don't give you control over the format, but that might be a worthwhile tradeoff.

Comment: There is also the possibility to generate a `build_details.c` file as `BUILT_SOURCES` which will avoid the overhead of compiling other code when only the build information has changed. Also, you can add a bogus stamp file to `BUILD_SOURCES` and have the recipe generate a new file `build_details.c.new` and only copy that `*.new` to `build_details.c` if the latter actually differs or does not exist. This avoids unnecessary recompiles if e.g. the git info has not changed.